# Mysql error when counting rows

Tags: php, mysql-num-rows

I have a problem when trying to count the rows in a table.

The variable $username_me equals to the session username. None of them is in an if or else statement.

The error i get is:

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/*****/public_html/******/sidebar.php on line 21

Line 21 is the last line in the code bit i pasted.

```
//Count unread oneliners
$oneliners_sql = "SELECT * FROM oneliners WHERE to_user='$username_me' AND read=0";
$oneliners_query = mysql_query($oneliners_sql);
$oneliners_num = mysql_num_rows($oneliners_query);
```

Comment: Change the second line to `$oneliners_query = mysql_query($oneliners_sql) or die( mysql_error() );`

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read=0' at line 1

But i have tried to do read='0'  too, and does not work eiher

Comment: Next do `echo $oneliners_sql;`. The problem is probably with `$username_me`.

Comment: @kaizo: probably `$username_me` contains a quote which is unbalancing/breaking the query. Dump a copy of `$oneliners_sql` here.

Comment: try to use backticks `\`read\``=0

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/yeyddhiw/public_html/underbyen/sidebar.php on line 21
SELECT * FROM oneliners WHERE to_user='kaizokupuffball' AND read='0'

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.1. `read` is mysql reserved word and must be quoted in backticks:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM oneliners WHERE to_user='$username_me' AND `read`=0";
```

.2. never use SELECT * to count rows. Use SELECT count(*) instead.

.3. always run all your queries this way to see any error occurred.

```
//Count unread oneliners
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM oneliners WHERE to_user='$username_me' AND `read`=0";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$oneliners_num = $row[0];
```

never use `die()` for this purpose, despite of all these stupid suggestions.

.4. Create a function for such a usual task.

```
function getOne($sql) {
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$sql);
  if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    return $row[0];
  }
}
```

So, you'll be able to get your num with one line

```
$oneliners_num = getOne("SELECT count(*) FROM oneliners WHERE to_user='$username_me' AND `read`=0");
```

Comment: Hi @Col.Shrapnel, just edited a couple of small typos, hope you don't mind :-)

Answer (score 3):

- **Your code is vulnerable of [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)**. There is also an [xkcd strip](http://xkcd.com/327/) on the argument :-)

If magic_quotes_gpc are not enabled (and they shouldn't, magic quotes were one of the many design mistakes of PHP and they are now deprecated), a hacker (or most likely a bot!) could freely alter your queries causing all sort of troubles to your site.

The proper way to fix this serious problem, is by using [Prepared Statements, for instance with PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Alternatively you can use mysql_real_escape_string:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM oneliners WHERE to_user='" . 
    mysql_real_escape_string($username_me) . "' AND `read`=0";
```

The trouble with `mysql_real_escape_string` is that you've to remember to always use it, while with prepared statements these issues are taken care for you. Also if you're not using prepared statements you can use [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to clean your integer inputs.

Let me stress it once more: **SANITIZING YOUR INPUTS IS VERY IMPORTANT**. You should not trust anything that comes from the user.

- **Your problem is caused by mysql_query returning FALSE when the query fails**. If the query fails, [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) return FALSE instead of resource. You can call mysql_num_rows on resource, not on FALSE. (From the manual: mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error).
- **The error is caused by the `read` field name**, since is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). Try to quote it with backticks (`) or even better, rename it.
- **To find out whether a row exists or not you can use `COUNT(*)` or `SELECT 1`**

With `COUNT` the query will always return a value of 0 or 1 (I suppose that you've a unique index on `to_user`), except when the query fails of course.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM oneliners WHERE to_user='" . 
    mysql_real_escape_string($username_me) . "' AND `read`=0";
```

With `SELECT 1` the query will return 1 if the row exists, otherwise it won't return any row.

```
$sql = "SELECT 1 FROM oneliners WHERE to_user='" . 
    mysql_real_escape_string($username_me) . "' AND `read`=0 LIMIT 1";
```

Which one to use depends if you need a count of the rows or you just need to know whether a row exists or not. If there is an unique index, they should be computationally very similar anyway.

Comment: yes exactly read the question first and then see my answer! problem was with ``

Comment: @waqaralamgir, well I mentioned it: "The error is caused by the read field name, since is a reserved word. Try to quote it with backticks (`) or even better, rename it.". It's a good idea to avoid rerserved words anyway.

Answer (score -1):

`mysql_query` returned **false** instread of mysql result. So, there are some errors on your query or connection. You may read error with `mysql_error`